# Align pathes next to each other in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path

I want to use Photoshop for drawing some simple shapes (I mostly need it for app development), and I just found the path drawing tool. I would like to put multiple pathes next to each other, and fill each one with a different color. But I don't know how to align them next to each other without having some 2-pixel gap between them. Maybe "align" is the wrong word here, because when I google for "photoshop align pathes", I get 30000 results, but the results are not answering my question at all. I have a picture to illustrate what I was trying to do:

[image: two-pathes]

As you can see in the picture, there is a gap between the two pathes. When I fill them, it doesn't look quite right:

[image: filled-pathes]

How do I place multiple pathes in a way that they don't overlap and don't have a gap between them?

Or maybe the path tool is not the best tool for my particular problem? I'm open to other suggestions as well. Maybe the way to go is to create a big path and then cut it with some kind of Autodesk/Maya-like "multicut tool"? I want to partition a rectangular canvas into a set of non-overlapping coherent subsets and give each one a different color (and maybe apply some filters afterwards).

Comment: You are trying to use Photoshop for vector images, and that's fine, but once you get to more complex designs, Photoshop is pretty basic when it comes to vector capabilities. In my opinion you'd be better using a vector image editor like Adobe Illustrator or even Inkscape (which is free).

Comment: There is no problem if you overlap them. You can always use a shape seelction to cut the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illustrator is way better program to do vectors, but for now I recommend more... horrifying step;P

So, all you need to do, is to create a shape of one layer (pink shape would be better), then bring it to the next layer and simply cut it. Maybe this screen would help:
[image]

I know it's very drammatic, but I think you should at least try it;P

Comment: Is it easier and less hacky in Illustrator? My motivation for using Photoshop was that I wouldn't need to install and learn yet another new program.

Comment: And you wouldn't need, Photoshop in my opinion is the best graphic program for everything;P But Adobe in many ways try to make our work easier, and for doing vectors Illustrator is the best choice.


Either way, you could still try my way to solve your problem in Photoshop;)

Comment: you're right. What I was trying to do is much easier achieved in Illustrator.